# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: reactjs, loops, for-loop, native

I got that error when I created for loop.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

The component which causes the error.

```
import React from "react";
import {TabWidgetNamespace} from "shared/namespaces/tab-widget.namespaces";
import {StyleSheet, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedbackComponent, View} from "react-native";

export class TabWidgetComponent extends React.Component<TabWidgetNamespace.TabWidgetPropsInterface, TabWidgetNamespace.TabWidgetStateInterface>{

style = StyleSheet.create({
    TabContainer: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    TabNavigation: {
        overflow: 'hidden'
    },
})

constructor(props: TabWidgetNamespace.TabWidgetPropsInterface) {
    super(props);
}

render(): React.ReactNode {

    const navigationItems = this.props.tabNavigation.map( (item, index) => (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedbackComponent key={index}>
                <Text>{item.label}</Text>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedbackComponent>
    ) );

    return(
        <View style={this.style.TabContainer}>
            <View style={this.style.TabNavigation}>
                {{ navigationItems }}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

I tried '*export default class ComponentName*' but I got same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to render an object here -

```
{{ navigationItems }}
```

You have extra parenthesis there. It should be -

```
 { navigationItems }
```

Comment: @AliBatuhanBayraktar Can you tell me which line exactly does the error throw at?

Comment: it said -> Check your code at tab-widget.component.tsx:23., 
    in TabWidgetComponent (at App.tsx:52)
    in RCTView (at App.tsx:51)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:26)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:25)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

Comment: @AliBatuhanBayraktar line 23 that is `<TouchableWithoutFeedbackComponent key={index}>`. Just checked react native documents it should be `TouchableWithoutFeedback` not `TouchableWithoutFeedbackComponent`. https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#example

Comment: You are king. :)